# Access to request source IP in Spring 3 MVC web application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller

Is there any way in Spring 3 MVC to gain access to the request header information (like source IP address etc.), when parsing a request in a @Controller?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can retrieve it from `HttpServletRequest`, using `getRemoteAddr()` to get access to user IP address and `getHeader()` to get header value.

For example

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/do-something")
    public void doSomething(HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String userIpAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
        final String userAgent = request.getHeader("user-agent");
        ....
    }
}
```

You may pass other parameters to the `doSomething()` method, like model or request params.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually busy deleting my post when I got the notification. Figured it out. Thanks anyway!

Comment: if client is behind proxy server then possible solution would by using  `String ip = req.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");`

Comment: and then handling it with condition like `if (ip == null) ip = request.getRemoteAddr();`

Comment: Since `request.getRemoteAddr()` is standard Servlets specification API that gets used not only in your code but in other 3rd party components as well, the right approach when behind a proxy is to plug in an implementation of `HttpServletRequest` that's aware of proxy headers. If you are using tomcat (for example), then you do that by adding `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" />` to your `server.xml`.

Comment: Why doesn't spring HttpHeader contain remote_addr?

Comment: @Normal the IP comes from socket connection not from headers