# Get the request sending URL in spring

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, servlets

I want to store the URL/ip that I received the request from.

For example I am (server) receives the request from ip address 176.15.14.3.

I want to get that ip address 176.15.14.3

Can I do that with Spring.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877350/how-to-extract-ip-address-in-spring-mvc-controller-get-call) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926001/access-to-request-source-ip-in-spring-3-mvc-web-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X-Forwarded-For value gives you the IP address of client. You can get the IP like below in spring.

```
String remoteAddress = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");//request--HTTPServletRequest Object
            if (remoteAddress == null) {
                remoteAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
            }
```

Comment: Your answer is nice. And correct, if theyre using a proxy, but you should really make it clear that this wont work unless you're using a reverse proxy, to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the [`HttpServletRequest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) Object, just call response.getRemoteAddr() which returns the remote host's ip represented as a string.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not gonna work if your server is behind a proxy - which is usually the case. @re350 answer is actually closer to perfect.